# How old is Yoda?

Tags: star-wars, age, yoda

In *Star Wars*, does anyone know how old Yoda is? Is it mentioned in any *Star Wars* movies?

Comment: The answers below say "900 years". But which "years" is that - Dagobah years? What's that in Earth years?

Comment: good point.. how did they meshed their years.. is it 365 day years?

Comment: why every one down voting this question? that much bad this one? if you don't like the question don't vote just delete the question please....!!!

Comment: Once again.. [you can't delete a question with an accepted answer, or answers that have been upvoted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25088/191489)

Comment: Also, this is in NO way primarily opinion based.

Comment: Not a downvoter, but they could be due to a lack of reseach. If you google "How old is Yoda", there is one of those google-box-things that says "900 years" in bold, followed by a quick explanation and a link. Whether that is what you were asking or not aside, I suppose its one possible explanation.

Comment: "if you don't like the question don't vote just delete the question please....!!! " that's not how things work here. we don't delete an on-topic question just because we don't like it.

Comment: @Wikis - A Galactic year is about the same as ours... The Coruscant solar cycle was 368 days long with a day consisting of 24 standard hours. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_Standard_Calendar

Comment: @Skooba: ah, but how long is a "standard hour"...? ;)

Comment: @Wikis - haha very true... the rabbit hole goes deeper... "60 seconds = 1 minute;
60 minutes = 1 hour;
24 hours = 1 day;
5 days = 1 week;
7 weeks = 1 month;
35 days = 1 month;
368 days = 1 year;
10 months + 3 festival weeks + 3 holidays = 1 year ------- Don't ask me how long a second is LOL

Comment: People are DVing this because they can quote the passage from memory. "When 900 years old you reach, look as good, you will not."

Comment: Ironically you asked a question about one of the few things we DO know about Yoda. [George Lucas kept the rest a mystery](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda's_species)

Comment: I told was 900 years

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Straight from [The Return of the Jedi](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Return-of-the-Jedi.html)

> YODA   (tickled, chuckles)
>   I do, yes, I do!  Sick have I become. Old and weak. (Points a crooked finger) **When nine hundred years old you reach, look as good you will not.**

Additionally, in case you think it's a case of hyperbole, the [Star Wars Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/yoda) mentions that he is at least 800 years old.

> Yoda was a legendary Jedi Master and stronger than most in his connection with the Force. Small in size but wise and powerful, he trained Jedi for over 800 years, playing integral roles in the Clone Wars, the instruction of Luke Skywalker, and unlocking the path to immortality.

Comment: dammit! just beat me

Comment: this much powerful master why didnt find Anikan sky walker bad side in the Jedi interview ?

Comment: He's the Methuselah of the Jedi.

Comment: @RANSARA009 i'm not a downvoter, but likely because this is very poorly researched. this line from yoda is a very famous line that anyone who has ever watched the movies should know.

Comment: I remember discussing this question (obviously not on Stack Exchange) back when the only answer from canon was that he was at least 800.

Answer (score 16):

An [archived blog entry on starwars.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20111119032510/http://blogs.starwars.com/holocron/13) written by [Leland Chee](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Leland_Chee) lists the major characters' birth years. It states that Yoda was born in 896 BBY, and that *Return of the Jedi* took place in 4 ABY, so **Yoda was 900 years old when he died**:

> **-896 Yoda**
>
> ~ -600 Jabba the Hutt
>
> ~ -200 Chewbacca
>
> -102 Count Dooku
>
> -92 Qui-Gon Jinn
>
> -82 Palpatine [47BrS:8:11]
>
> -72 Mace Windu
>
> -66 Jango Fett
>
> -57 Obi-Wan Kenobi
>
> -46 Padmé Amidala
>
> -41.9 Anakin Skywalker
>
> -32 Star Wars: Episode I The Phantom Menace [3:4:14]
>
> -31.5 Boba Fett
>
> -31 Lando Calrissian
>
> -29 Han Solo
>
> -22 Star Wars: Episode II Attack of the Clones [13:5:21]
>
> -21 Wedge Antilles
>
> -19 Star Wars: Episode III Revenge of the Sith [16:5:23]
>
> -19 Luke Skywalker & Princess Leia (Luke born first)
>
> -18 Corran Horn
>
> -18 Mara Jade Skywalker
>
> 0 Star Wars: Episode IV A New Hope
>
> 3 Star Wars: Episode V The Empire Strikes Back
>
> **4 Star Wars: Episode VI Return of the Jedi**
>
> 9 Jaina & Jacen Solo (Jaina born first)
>
> 10 Anakin Solo
>
> 26.5 Ben Skywalker

This out-of-universe statement indicates that Yoda had reached literally 900 years old when he died (he didn't exaggerate when he told Luke that "when 900 years old you reach, look as good you will not"). Since Leland Chee is responsible for *Star Wars* canon (even post-Disney), this is canon information.

Comment: I think it's kind of lame that they made it exactly 900, taking the number so literally.

Comment: @corsiKa Yeah, it would have been better if they'd made him >900 (like 920 or so) -- the Episode VI line would still be true but his age would seem less contrived.

Comment: I'm honestly pretty astounded that Qui-Gon was 92.

Comment: @Jules he wasn't, he was born in 92 BBY, so he was only 60 when Episode 1 took place.  Still impressive considering Obi-Wan was younger than this when he met Luke (57), and he looked a lot older.

Comment: @corsiKa It's likely they never really thought about an exact number until waaaaaaay after the release of RotJ. When someone finally had to think of a birthyear for yoda, he likely referenced the movie literally.

Comment: @null exactly 900 is no more contrived than exactly 920, or exactly 913, etc

Comment: Qui-Gon was supposed to be 60 in TPM? No wonder he got his butt handed to him by Darth Maul...

Answer (score 4):

### 900 Years

Yoda tells Luke in *The Return of the Jedi*

> When 900 years old you reach, look as good you will not

Answer (score 3):

Just to a give another answer from a [*certain point of view*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda/Legends#cite_note-Jedi_vs._Sith-0)... Legends tells us that Yoda is indeed exactly 900 years old.

- Born in 896 BBY
- Died in 4 ABY

However, my hunch is that this was done to match the line from *Return of the Jedi*...